# Comparing two numbers with regex getting "Unexpected quantifier" error on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have to compare two numbers and I used regular expression. while running in IE its getting error like `Unexpected quantifier`, Please suggest me the solution,

```js
var creditAmount = "1,00,567.60";
 var debitAccount = "2,45,678.89";
 var difference = (parseFloat(creditAmount) - parseFloat(debitAccount)).toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",").replace("-", "");
 console.log(difference);
```

Comment: Can we back up and first focus on why you're using regexp for this? Keep simple tasks written with simple code: JS can do arithemtics just fine, and `Number.toLocaleString` has been in JS since before IE6.

Comment: Actually my requirement like I'm getting plain values like 104567.78, I have to show in the table like comma separated and I need to get the difference of two columns. for showing commas I used regular expression. Above snipper I just gave small example values.

Comment: Cool: don't? turn them into numbers, get the difference, then format them either using localestring formatting, or even using [NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) which is supported by IE11. `new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(1234567.89)` will give you `1,234,567.89`. No regexp required.

Comment: Thank you and Let me check for this way..